# CASE/WHEN in WHERE condition depending on row index

Tags: mysql

To make it simple I have table with columns:

```
id | title | image | video
```

where image and video are: name-of-image.jpg/name-of-video.mp4 or NULL. How can I select first 3 rows only containing image and then 1 row containing video and so on, like:

```
1 image

2 image

3 image

4 video

5 image

6 image

7 image

8 video
```

I'm using PHP/MySQL. I need to take max 1000 rows and then just echo rows, my query is:

```
SET @rownum:=0;
SELECT title, image, video, date_published, @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownumber 
FROM `stories` 
WHERE 
    CASE
        WHEN @rownum%3=0 THEN image IS NOT NULL
        ELSE video IS NOT NULL
    END
   AND (`language_id`='7')
ORDER BY `date_published` DESC 
LIMIT 200
```

I need to implement what I wrote above, to return first 3 rows containing image and next 1 containing video. But I cannot use @rownum in WHERE condition and that would be perfect way to select my sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you perform the filtering in a outer query like

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT title, image, video, date_published, 
`language_id`, @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownumber 
FROM `stories`, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r ) xx
WHERE 
    CASE
        WHEN rownumber%3=0 THEN image IS NOT NULL
        ELSE video IS NOT NULL
    END
   AND (`language_id`='7')
ORDER BY `date_published` DESC 
LIMIT 200
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @rownum:=0' at line 2

Comment: @FosAvance, see edit in answer. Should work fine now.

Comment: It's fine but @rownum is random, it's not going from 1